# Python Selenium with BeautifulSoup for multiple links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to extract links from multiple web pages.Everything works fine for extract but for multiple urls first url getting twice and last one not getting.What is the reason for this?

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLs = ["https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/1","https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/2",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/3","https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/4","https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/5",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/6","https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/7"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

file = open('linkler.csv', 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['linkler'])


for link in URLs:
  driver.get(link)

  html_source = driver.page_source

  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

  for links in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/")}):
    writer.writerow([links.get('href')])


driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "last one not getting" - Please explain in detail and improve your question. Thanks

Comment: I mean the last url in the url list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of scan i get the problem ,  the site is blocking ur requests if there's no rest time so i fix it by adding sleep time ! now your code will work fine i test it !

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

URLs = ["https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/1",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/2",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/3",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/4",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/5",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/6",
        "https://www.oddsportal1.com/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/results/#/page/7"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

file = open('linkler.csv', 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['linkler'])

for link in URLs:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(5)
    html_source = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

    for links in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/")}):
        writer.writerow([links.get('href')])

driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for effort.That helped a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

### What happens?

Getting some duplicates is caused by duplicates on the sites and your matching `regex`, so Script works as designed - Good news you can fix that ;)

### How to avoid writing duplicates?

Create a `list` that contains only unique `href` and check if new scraped `href` is in or not. In case that not write it to csv and also update the `list` (It is also possible, to write list later to csv.)

**Example**

```
...
file = open('linkler.csv', 'w+', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(['linkler'])

hrefList = []

for link in URLs:
    driver.get(link)

    html_source = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
    
    for links in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/soccer/turkey/super-lig-2019-2020/")}):
        if links.get('href') not in hrefList:
            hrefList.append(links.get('href'))
            writer.writerow([links.get('href')])

file.close()
...
```